# How to disable break button that comes at the bottom of jodit editor?

Tags: reactjs, angular, typescript, wysiwyg, jodit

I have tried disabling "enter" plugin but still it shows up.

Button usually shows up at the mouse position at the bottom of the editor with tooltip showing as "break". When clicked on button it creates a br tag.

Comment: please share the minimal reproducible code if possible a stackblitz where the issue happens!

Comment: @NarenMurali You can visit https://xdsoft.net/jodit/ and in the editor try to check the issue

Comment: Umang update the Question with code or link to code.

Answer (score 0):

After trying many things, I discovered the "break" button is named "add-new-line" plugin. So you can disable it in the config:

```
'disablePlugins': 'add-new-line'
```